# echo data from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

hi everybody have a good day .
i have an question regarding to echo value form mysql database
Now i have a table name ---> `materialachievement`
Inside the table i have 3 column (chapter ,subchapter and part)

the data is like below:

```
chapter      subchapter         part
-------------------------------------
2               2.1               1
2               2.1               2
2               2.1               3
2               2.2               1
2               2.2               2
3               3.1               1
3               3.1               1
-------------------------------------
```

Now i want do a table to echo chapter 2 and 3
and inside chapter 2 has subchapter 2.1 and subchapter 2.2
inside subchapter 2.1 has part 1 , 2 , 3 and inside subchapter 2.2 has part 1 , 2

the structure is like :

```
2
 2.1
    1
    2
    3
 2.2
    1
    2
```

So my question is how can i just echo chapter 2 for once , then subchapter 2.1 for once , then go to part 1 , 2 , 3 ? same with sunchapter 2.2.

```
$query="SELECT * FROM materialachievement WHERE sID=$id GROUP BY (chapter and subchapter) ORDER BY chapter ASC , subchapter ASC ";

$result=mysql_query($query,$conn);

if($result === FALSE) 
{
die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
}

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $chapter = $row['chapter'];
    $subchapter = $row['subchapter'];

    echo "<br>Chapter :".$chapter."<br>";
    echo "<br>Subchapter :".$subchapter."<br>";
}
```

now the result suppose be : chapter 2 , subchapter 2.1 , subchapter 2.2 , subchapter 2.3
and chapter 3 , subchapter 3.1 , subchapter 3.2

Comment: Show what you've tried and we'll help you fix it. You basically just need to save the last chapter and subchapter in a variable, and check if the new row is different.

Comment: $query="SELECT * FROM materialachievement WHERE sID=$id GROUP BY (chapter and subchapter) ORDER BY chapter ASC , subchapter ASC ";
     $result=mysql_query($query,$conn);
if($result === FALSE) {
die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
}
 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
         {
          $chapter = $row['chapter'];
          $subchapter = $row['subchapter'];
          
          echo "<br>Chapter :".$chapter."<br>";
          echo "<br>Chapter :".$subchapter."<br>";
}

Comment: Put it in your question so it's properly formatted.

Comment: but this code only echo Chapter :2 and Chapter :2.1 
and suppose have chapter 2 ,  subchapter 2.1 , 2.2 , 2.3
and chapter 3 , subchapter 3.1 , 3.2

Comment: I can't read your code. Edit your question so it's nicely formatted.

Comment: @Barmar may i know how to put it ? because i not sure where to post it
thanks

Comment: Click the "edit" link below the question and update your question. Use the `{}` tool to mark it as code.

Comment: Show the code you've written that tries to solve the problem.

Comment: Your `GROUP BY` clause makes no sense. `(chapter AND subchapter)` is the same for all rows, because this is a boolean expression that evaluates to `true` unless either of them is `0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$query="SELECT * FROM materialachievement WHERE sID=$id ORDER BY chapter ASC, subchapter ASC, part ASC ";

$result=mysql_query($query,$conn);

if($result === FALSE) 
{
die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
}

$last_chapter = null;
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $chapter = $row['chapter'];
    $subchapter = $row['subchapter'];
    $part = $row['part'];
    if ($last_chapter !=== $chapter) {
        echo "Chapter: $chapter<br>";
        $last_chapter = $chapter;
        $last_subchapter = null;
    }
    if ($subchapter !== $last_subchapter) {
        echo "Subchapter: $subchapter<br>";
        $last_subchapter = $subchapter;
    }
    echo "Part: $part<br>";
}
```

Comment: thank you very much , pro man , u really professional 
u help be to solve this problem which i have stuck for many days,
thanks again for the help and i think i found the right channel to ask my problem , thanks Barmer.

Comment: Many days to solve this trivial problem? How hard is it to just set a variable to see if you've already printed something?

Comment: hehe , because i still newbies in php , mysql 
and my basic is not strong enough 
that why stuck for many day
last time i have another problem which already solve stuck for few week , so sad...
but luckily, u help me solve the problem within a second
thanks again

Answer (score 1):

hope this help

```
$data=array();
$data[] = array("chapter" => "2",                "subchapter" => "2.1",               "part" => "1"              );
$data[] = array("chapter" => "2",                "subchapter" => "2.1",               "part" => "2"              );
$data[] = array("chapter" => "2",                "subchapter" => "2.1",               "part" => "3"              );

$data[] = array("chapter" => "2",                "subchapter" => "2.2",               "part" => "1"              );
$data[] = array("chapter" => "2",                "subchapter" => "2.2",               "part" => "2"              );

$data[] = array("chapter" => "3",                "subchapter" => "3.1",               "part" => "1"              );
$data[] = array("chapter" => "3",                "subchapter" => "3.1",               "part" => "1"              );

$new_array=array();

foreach($data AS $v){

    if(!array_key_exists($v['chapter'],$new_array )){
        $new_array[$v['chapter']]=array();
    }
     if(!array_key_exists($v['subchapter'],$new_array[$v['chapter']]) ){
        $new_array[$v['chapter']][$v['subchapter']]=array();
    }
    $new_array[$v['chapter']][$v['subchapter']]=$v['part'];

}

print_r($new_array);
```

output

```
    Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [2.1] => 3
            [2.2] => 2
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [3.1] => 1
        )

)
```

Comment: thanks for your help ,but my problem is the data in mysql database does not static
For example :
now my database only have chapter 2 and 3 , then subchapter .....
but later user can add more chapter like chapter 4 ,5 ....
so...

Comment: $data just sample , sql query to array then fromat it to 2D array , then use...so chapter 4 ,5...... can display

Comment: thanks again for help but i think i already got the answer from Barmar , 
anyway thanks again for your help.